# Writing out huge json (4 Gb) with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a really huge json object (created with a JavaScript parser called espree, contains an array of objects). I want to write it to a .json file, but it fails every time with memory allocation problems (My heap size is 22 Gb).

As far as I understand, the buffer gets overloaded while the data is not being written into file.

If I use synchronous file operations only, the output gets written into the file, but the running time of my application exploads.

Solutions I have tried and failed (tried to serialize the whole object, then tried to serialize the items of the array):

- JSON.stringify
- JSONStream
- big-json (which should be serialize the object as a stream, but the buffer still gets overloaded..)
- watching for drain events

Here is the current code:

```
const bjson= require('big-json');

function save(result) {
    let outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(/*path*/);

    const stringifyStream = bjson.createStringifyStream({
        body: result
    });

    function write(d) {
        let result = outputStream.write(d);
        if (!result) {
            outputStream.once('drain', write);
        }
    }

    stringifyStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        writeData(chunk);
    });

    stringifyStream.on('end', function () {
        outputStream.end();
    });
}

let results = [/*results as an array, containing lots of json objects*/];
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    save(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: Usually you would want to pipe to the output steam. On data doesn't do backpressuring. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/

Comment: Why on earth would you write this to a file, instead of writing it to a database? That's literally what databases were invented for, and most current versions even come with JSON datatypes if you really don't want efficiency and just want a "document" store. And then you make some consuming script access that DB and read the data in as sets of manageable size. While taking advantage of the fact that the DB itself can do a whole bunch of number crunching and data aggregation using DB/SQL instructions.

Comment: JSON is probably the wrong choice here... why not use ND-JSON instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Portability is a good reason to use JSON.  There are still plenty of people throwing CSVs around, just because everything can use it.  Better to have JSON, where at least we have structure and typing.  But, I have a hunch that this is actually a number of records, in which case ND-JSON would be a better choice.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware They are parsing JavaScript source code into an AST using espree. They may not have much choice but to read it all at once.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we haven't got much option. After building these json object, we add things to it, and then we want to write it to file. in most of the cases, it works pretty well, I came across this problem while analyzing the JS source of [DCGAN](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/tree/master/web/js). layers.js has some nasty stuff which kills the json writing i think.

Answer (score 0):

Performance issue came from JSON transformation to string. I have the same issue and I solved that by storing data with msgpack format.

Has explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msgpack-lite), I installed msgpack-lite in my projet with npm :

```
npm install msgpack-lite
```

I code that for storing my JSON object :

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var msgpack = require("msgpack-lite");

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("file.msp");
var encodeStream = msgpack.createEncodeStream();
encodeStream.pipe(writeStream);

// send multiple objects to stream
encodeStream.write(myBigObject);

// call this once you're done writing to the stream.
encodeStream.end();
```

And that for reading my file and restore my object. I don't know why it doesn't works with Streams :

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var msgpack = require("msgpack-lite");

var buffer = fs.readFileSync("file.msp");
var myBigObject = msgpack.decode(buffer);
```